# Remove ’ on string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have a word like this `What’s On`. How to remove space and `’`?

I can remove space like so `data.caption.replace(/ +/g, "")` How to do the other part?

Comment: `/[’ ]+/g` for a character set

Comment: @Taplar Thanks working fine.

Comment: what's the desired output you want? `Whats on` or `Whatson`?

Comment: @Ammar The requirements are stated in the question. Although I have to admit, questions like this confuse me since it's readily searchable and regex 101.

Comment: @Taplar Can you tell me how to write `apostrophe` using US key bord?

Comment: I just did a copy and paste.  That may be a character generated more frequently from an iOS machine.

Comment: @Taplar Hmm... You can put your answer no?

Comment: `'What’s On'.replace(/[^\w]/g, '')`, you could replace anything that is a non-word character. However this may not work for you if you only want those two characters to be removed.

Comment: @Taplar Or when foolish people think you can cut-and-paste from arbitrary sources. Which is a pet-peeve.

Comment: @Sampath The same way you got it into your question.

Comment: @DaveNewton oh, I absolutely agree.  At one point in my career, having to deal with clients copy and pasting from Word documents into WYSIWYG components was a pita for me. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[]` to provide a character set.  So in this case, the following would match against the weird quote and a space.

```
/[’ ]+/g
```

Answer (score 0):

This expresion might simply work:

```
\s*’
```

which checks for 0 or more spaces prior to `’`.

```js
console.log("What          ’s On ?".replace(/\s*’/,""));
console.log("What          ’s On ?".replace(/[\s’]+/,""));
```

Or if we wish to replace all spaces:

```js
const regex = /([^\s’]+)|(.+?)/gm;
const str = `What          ’s    On ?`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IwViFu/1/)

Comment: Nothing was said about spaces prior to the apostrophe.

Comment: Oh.. How complex your solution is?